# Is Main.strings (English) ever required since we already have Main.storyboard (Base)?

Tags: ios, swift

We plan to support 20+ different languages, we wish to do it right at early stage.

Our goal is to support 20+ different non-English language. Anything else will be fall back to default English.

[image]

I was wondering, is `Main.strings (English)` ever required, since we already have `Main.storyboard (Base)`. Should we still keep and maintain `Main.strings (English)` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual translations are stored in the language files. One can argue that MainStoryboard holds all the English strings. Yet it gives you the power to change translations in the English file only and keep in the storyboard strings not for final user display. I found that comes in handy not too rarely.

Yet there is no technical need. I also maintain apps without the English strings file for xib/storyboard files and they work as expected.